# Create New Columns from a DateTime Column

Tags: datetime, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, derived-column

This is my SSIS excerise

I have a DATETIME column, what I want is to get the Month and Year from " DATETIME " column and load it into a new column called “Month_Year” and then get day from the same " DATETIME " and load it into a new column called "day"

Visually

1. Source Column:

DATETIME

2. Destination Column:

Month_Year  Day

Bottom line is I need to break DATETIME into two column Month_Year and Day.

**Example**

```
DATETIME
2010-01-01

Month_YEAR     DAY
201001         01`
```

The Source Column is 2010-01-01
The Destination Columns will be 201001 And 01

Answer (score 1):

Simple, first create a Derived Column component in your flow task.
Then, in the component, create a new column, call it `MONTH_YEAR` and in the Expression field type:

```
 (DT_WSTR, 10)DATEPART(month, [YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN]) +
 "_" + (DT_WSTR, 4)DATEPART(year, [YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN])
```

Then for the day piece do the same thing only creating a new column called `DAY` and pull the day piece out from `DATEPART(..).`

Since you created those as new columns you can then use them in the data flow as wished.